# Parallel vs Series Circuit

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electrical-resistance, batteries

[image]

If the M lamp breask, why does L get brighter? I tried using the equation,

$$V=IR \qquad \qquad \text{with} \qquad \qquad \frac{1}{R_{eq}} = \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2}$$

but it seems like it will decrease the voltage. Won't that make the light dimmer?Am I missing something?

Comment: This is a question from the official GCE test and the answer is D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If M breaks then the current through L increases because there is no shunt through M. Also, the resistance of the left hand side increases when the parallel path is disrupted. Therefore the current through the right hand side decreases. N dims.

Comment: I tried linking your explanation with the equations and it makes a lot of sense now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

*Note :-* In my answer, I have assumed all the identical lamps to have a resistance of $R$.

**Before breaking M :-** If we assume the battery to have an e.m.f. of $E$. Since the internal resistance of the battery is negligible, thus tye the potential difference across the terminals of the battery will be $E$. And this will also be the potential difference across the remaining circuit consisting of the lamps.

Now, if you evaluate the equivalent resistance of both L and M using the formula for equivalent resistance of two resistors in parallel combination (which you have already stated in your question), then it comes out to be $\frac{R}{2}$. And the resistance of N is already know to be $R$. Now here we will use the fact that in a series of resistances, the voltage across a resistor is proportional to its resistance. That is because the current through every resistor is the same, so

$$V=IR \Rightarrow V \propto R$$

Now in this case, divide the voltages like this. You will end up with a potential difference of $\frac{E}{3}$ across the combination of L and M. And since L and M are in parallel, the voltage across the combination is, in fact, the voltages across L and M.

**After M breaks :-** Now again, as we did in the previous case, if you divide the voltages, you will easily be able to see the increase in the potential difference across L, and thus the increase in brightness. Moreover, this case is easier than the previous one. Try it yourself.

Comment: There is a reason why I did not help you out till your final answer. Here at Physics SE, we believe that one learns best when he/she does solve his/her problems himself. So we only guide or teach, rather than spoonfeeding you with the complete solution. Welcome to Physics SE!!

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explaination~ It is a little bit confusing, but I get a general idea of what you are trying to say

Comment: @水野冬夜 Try writing out the equations. Try to figure it out yourself. You will surely get a feel for it. It's quite simple :).

Comment: Already figured out